# Merge multiple rows based on column & sum time values in Excel for MAC

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, pivot, duration

I have a report pulled from KRONOS daily and emailed to me which has 4 columns. The names are down the first column, employee ID, type of pay, hours to pay in that order. I just need to combine the hours so that there is one value per row and just one name. I tried using an easy pivot table but that failed for 2 reasons.

1. I couldn't figure out how to sum duration of hours in 00:00 format
   (tried every single option in field settings) either got N/a or the count of instances.
2. Even if it worked, I would like to figure out how to exclude the 1.00 hour penalty from the type of pay column indicated by "LP CA Meal Penalty"

I tried to paste the actual tables here but it wouldnt let me so below is my best attempt to replicate issue for one employee.

Curt, Cathy    90066408    LP CA Meal Penalty    1.00

Curt, Cathy    90066408    LP Overtime           1.77

Curt, Cathy    90066408    LP Regular            8.00

Result desired:
Curt, Cathy    90066408        =                  9.77

Do Not want: Curt, Cathy    90066408          =                10.77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `Column A:D` and result needs to be displayed from `Column G`,

To get all the unique **`Names`** from `Column A` enter the following formula in `Cell G2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range `$A$2:$A$9` as per data in `Column A`.

Now, to get corresponding **`Employee ID`**, enter the following formula in `Cell H2`

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,A2:D9,2)
or
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$9,0))
```

Finally, to get **`Total Hours`**, enter the below formula in `Cell I2`

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9,$A$2:$A$9,G2,$C$2:$C$9,"<>LP CA Meal Penalty")
or
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$9)*($A$2:$A$9=G2)*($C$2:$C$9<>"LP CA Meal Penalty"))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

***EDIT :***

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9,$A$2:$A$9,G2,$C$2:$C$9,"<>LP CA Meal Penalty",$C$2:$C$9,"<>LP CA Rest Break Penalty")
or
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$9)*($A$2:$A$9=G2)*($C$2:$C$9<>"LP CA Meal Penalty")*($C$2:$C$9<>"LP CA Rest Break Penalty"))
```

Comment: AMAZING !!! It worked and I am forever grateful. I have another favor to ask - I just realized there is another type of pay I need to exclude from column C in addition to the LP CA Meal Penalty. The cell reads "LP CA Rest Break Penalty" -- How do I also exclude that? I tried to mimic both sumif and sumproduct logic but just kept getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to do is filter by your third column and exclude in the filter the "LP CA Meal Penalty".

Attached are examples of my result and my filter selection on my pivot table.
[Result gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fomcm.png)

[Filter excluding the unwanted work hour type from the sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYVhs.png)

Let me know if this works for  you.

Comment: Thank you for the dummy reminder to put the type of pay code into the filter...duhhh.  BUT I am still getting zeroes for the sum?

Comment: I took a screenshot of pivot but dont know how to share with you

Comment: In the sum, you should have SUM as the type of field, with NO CALCULATION in field display options. Regarding your requirement of number format hh:mm, that is entirely dependant on your source data. If it's not in that format, converting to hh:mm will require some extra work. If the source is in the same format, just go to "number format" in the fiel options and set it to custom and type hh:mm. What is the  result you want and what is the solution we came to together lacking?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use `SUMIFS` as the example I show you above and the formula to use is:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$9,$A$2:$A$9,F2,$C$2:$C$9,"<>"&"LP CA Meal Penalty")
```

This will exclude `LP CA Meal Penalty` from the computation.

Also, for the time format, the requirement is not so clear but this is `hh:mm` what I understand that you want.  The formula you can use is:

```
=TEXT(H2/24,"hh:mm")
```

Please tweak the range that fits your data structure and let me know if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much. I am still adjusting my table to match your suggestions. I wish I wouldn't have simplified my original table so I could have just plugged and played your formula.     Is there a work around as a new user so you can see my table? This site is the best in terms of users being helpful but geez its hard for a new user....

Comment: You can take a screenshot of your data (maybe also including row and column numbers) and paste to your question.  You can simply click the `edit` button underneath your question.  Once you get in, you should see a `img` icon (with mountain) for you to upload the pic.